# ansible + vmware vm deploy

Tags: ansible, vmware

При помощи рецептов ansible можно деплоить ВМ vmware через vcenter. Есть возможно так же сразу и кастомизировать ВМ внутри через cloud init.
Вопрос:
Не очень понимаю как заставить работать этот этот мехинизм применительно к обычный ВМ. Должна ли быть какая-то отдельная инфраструктура для этого?

Comment: Доги уже прочли по VMWare модулям? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html#vmware

Answer (score 2):

Все конечно зависит от того что вы вкладываете в понятие обычной ВМ, но допустим у вас установлен VirtualBox. Все что вам необходимо это поставить еще к нему Ruby и самое важное поставить - [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/index.html)

Vagrant поможет вам управлять вашей средой виртуализации он поддерживает таких провайдеров виртуализации как: VirtualBox, Hyper-V, Docker и др. (VMWare тоже поддерживает но рекомендуют использовать VirtualBox вместо него так как он более стабилен)

Итак сама суть поднять виртуальную машину Debian Jessie x64 при помщи Vagrant можно просто используя 2 команды:

```
vagrant init debian/jessie64
vagrant up
```

Первая  команда создаст файл конфигурации Vagrantfile в директории где вы выполняете команду, а вторая скачает подготовленный образ debian/jessie и запустит его. Далее вы можете модифицировать файл Vagrantfile добавив в него строки

```
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose = "vvv"
    ansible.playbook = "playbook_path/playbook.yml"
  end
```

после чего выполнить команду

```
vagrant provision
```

или перезапустить запущенную ВМ и плейбук начнет применяться. Для Vagrant можно в playbook в Hosts указать all тогда не будет проблем с применением его на ВМ.

Вторая часть вопроса с cloud-init если у вас есть готовый iso подключите его добавив строку в Vagrantfile

```
CLOUD_CONFIG_PATH = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "localpathiso\cloud-init.iso")
```

P.S. Важно предварительно поискать необходимый вам образ ВМ на [Vagrant Cloud](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search).

Надеюсь я смог дать нужный вам ответ.